# PDF owner and user passwords

Tags: pdf

When setting Access permissions in a PDF, I need to specify an owner password, but do I need to also specify the encryption level, or is that needed only for a user password?

I'm reading the PDF specification (pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) about security handlers, but it's not a very easy read so I'd rather ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access permissions can be set only when the document is encrypted. It does not matter whether you set or not the owner and/or user password, you have to set all the encryption related properties, algorithm, key size, version, revision, etc.

Comment: I suspected it was that way but I figured since access restrictions depend on the good-will of the PDF reader to honor them, that there isn't any real encryption in the PDF. Now for a user password the PDF would be encrypted because the reader doesn't need to be able to render it before you've given the password.